# Book (series?) in which a word defeats a dark lord/evil king

Tags: story-identification, books, young-adult

I have remembered a middle-grade book (series?) that I'd read probably around 4th-6th grade. These are all the details I can remember:

- It was a medieval fantasy esque setting.
- It featured a world with some sort of king or dark lord that the protagonist was trying to defeat - for some reason, I don't remember why, this king was almost undefeatable. He could only be defeated by a secret word.
- Parts of the secret word were scattered around the land in syllables.
- The book begun with an ominous prologue in which a character had finally gathered all the parts of the word, and confronted the king - I think he might've been captured or something like that, and was brought before the king. When he said the word, it didn't work. I don't remember perfectly, but it might've been because the 'king' was an imposter, staged there to make the person say it and then the real king would come out.
- After saying the word, the person who said it immediately forgets it.

Comment: Honorable mention for Ursula LeGuin's "The Word of Unbinding" which treats very similar themes, collected in *The Wind's Twelve Quarters*... if I recall correctly, she wrote this before *A Wizard of Earthsea*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is [Beyonders: A World Without Heroes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beyonders:_A_World_Without_Heroes) by Brandon Mull.

> After arriving at the blind king's decrepit keep, Jason learns that
>   the "blind king" is really Galloran, a broken hero who already tried
>   and failed on the same quest that Jason is now committed to. A few
>   moments after learning of Galloran's true identity, Jason is
>   introduced to Rachel, a girl his age from earth, who arrived in Lyrian
>   by walking through a stone arch. Galloran then tells them that they
>   are central to a prophecy spoken by a powerful seer, one in which they
>   will destroy the tyrannical wizard emperor, Maldor. **Galloran points
>   out that the easiest (though still extremely difficult) way to
>   accomplish this is to seek a Word of power that when spoken in
>   Maldor's presence will theoretically destroy him. There are six
>   syllables to The Word, the first of which had already been discovered
>   by Jason at the repository of learning. Each syllable of The Word is
>   protected by a guardian, each of whom will only reveal their syllable
>   to those embarked on the quest to destroy Maldor.** However, some
>   syllables have also been written down (such as the one at the
>   repository of learning), removing the necessity of directly seeking
>   out the guardians of those syllables. They may only speak or write The
>   Word in its entirety once, after which the individual that did so will
>   forget it. Since Jason was the only one to read the book containing
>   this information, Rachel may opt out. However, she decides to join
>   him. Satisfied with their decision, Galloran presents Jason with a
>   dagger whose blade shoots out of the handle at the pressing of a
>   button on the pommel, while Rachel is given an orantium sphere, a type
>   of grenade with an explosive crystal encased in glass that explodes
>   when exposed to air or water. After being given a starting point by
>   Galloran, Jason and Rachel embark on a very long quest for The Word.

[image]

Comment: Ah, that's definitely it, thank you! Impressively speedy search!

Comment: [I remain, as ever, impressively modest](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1wrSsIVqHpM)